# convert values in a python list based on value

Tags: python, list

I have a python list of lists.  The last 'column' of the list contains a target variable, with the values 2 or 4.  I want to convert these values into 0 (if 2) or 1 (if 4).  I also want to maintain the list structure as is.

```
myList = [[1,2,3,2],[1,2,2,2],[1,3,4,4]]
newList = [[1,2,3,0],[1,2,2,0],[1,3,4,1]]
```

I can convert the list into a numpy array first by doing this:

```
import numpy as np
myList = np.array(myList)
```

Then I can get the last column by doing the following:

```
myList[:, -1]
```

Just not sure how to change the values in it.  I know once I've done, I can convert the data back into the original list format by doing the following:

```
myList = myList.astype(float).tolist()
```

Comment: You'll need to write code to do that, which you appear to have not even attempted to do yet.

Comment: `for a in myList: a[-1] //= 4`

Comment: I've added additional code as per the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with the comma slice, then you can do it in two steps like this:

```
import numpy as np

myList = [[1,2,3,2],[1,2,2,2],[1,3,4,4]]
myList = np.array(myList)

myList[:,-1][myList[:,-1] == 2] = 0
myList[:,-1][myList[:,-1] == 4] = 1

# myList = myList.astype(float).tolist()

print(myList)
```

If you want to keep the original unaffected, then just do a deep copy:

```
import copy
import numpy as np

myList = [[1,2,3,2],[1,2,2,2],[1,3,4,4]]
myList = np.array(myList)

newList = copy.deepcopy(myList)

newList[:,-1][newList[:,-1] == 2] = 0
newList[:,-1][newList[:,-1] == 4] = 1

# newList = newList.astype(float).tolist()

print(newList)
```

The output in both cases is:

```
[[1 2 3 0]
 [1 2 2 0]
 [1 3 4 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Very basic option:

```py
from copy import deepcopy
# so you don't overwrite the original list
myList = [[1,2,3,2],[1,2,2,2],[1,3,4,4]]

def myFunc(x):
    if x[3] == 2:
        x[3] = 0
        return x
    elif  x[3] == 4:
        x[3] = 1
        return x
    else:
        return x

# make a deep copy    
newList = deepcopy(myList)

# apply the function
newList = list(map(myFunc,newList))
```